# Should I put all header files inside the include dir?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to find the answer to this question using the search function, but only came accross questions about missing header files etc.

Background: in the past 10 years of coding C/C++ I've learned that it's important to think about the (external) interface of the code I write. It's generally a good idea to keep it small and simple, hiding implementation details as much as I can. As a result, typically a software package/library that I would develop would have an `include` directory that only contains the header files that I want to expose to the users of that package/library, while the rest of the headers that are only intended for internal use are located in the `src` directory.

Now I'm getting started with ROS and I see quite a few packages that seem to put `.h` files in `include` and `.cpp` files in `src`. Is there are specific reason to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290692/should-i-put-all-header-files-inside-the-include-dir?/) by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2018-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This will be an opiniated answer, but just to provide you with my own insight / experience:

> Now I'm getting started with ROS and I see quite a few packages that seem to put `.h` files in `include` and `.cpp` files in `src`. Is there are specific reason to do this?

`include` directories are only exported (ie: added to the public interface of a ROS package) if that directory is explicitly passed to the `catkin_package(.. INCLUDE_DIRS ..)` call as an argument. Packages which have no headers that should be part of the public interface should not do this. Packages which just provide 'top level' nodes, but no libraries are examples of pkgs that should probably not have their `include` directory exposed by `catkin_package(..)`.

So if we accept that, any header in `$pkg_dir/include` (or any other folder with headers that is passed to `catkin_package(..)`) always defines the public interface of a package. And inverting this: `$pkg_dir/include` should only contain headers that are intended to be part of that same public interface (again: assuming that `$pkg_dir/include` is actually passed to `catkin_package(..)`).

Now as to whether this 'best practice' is adopted by the ROS community as a whole I cannot say. It is however how I've structured my packages, and it works well for me.

I believe this would align with what you already wrote yourself: only add public headers to a publicly-visible include folder, and keep the rest private. So I would recommend you to keep doing what you already have been doing, and consider the `$pkg_dir/include` directory as the default location for the public interface of any/your package(s).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-09**:
Note that there are other techniques to hide implementation details (that you're probably familiar with). Following a specific file/directory layout/structure is a rather coarse, but effective, first step.

**Comment by [Mbuijs](https://answers.ros.org/users/33718/mbuijs/) on 2018-05-09**:
Thanks for the extensive explanation.

The first packages I was setting up were 'top level' nodes, so I did not pass `include` to `catkin_package(..)`. In practice I didn't have any public header files and therefore didn't even create the `include` dir, instead just put everything in `src`.